# Replace outliers with median exept NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, outliers

I would like to replace outliers with median in a dataframe but only outliers and not NaN.

First :

```
      January  February 
0      -5.0     -7.0 
1      -6.0     -6.0 
2      -5.0     -5.0  
3      -3.0     -6.0 
4      -6.0     -8.0   
5     -11.0     -9.0    
6      -6.0      5.0    
7      -8.0    -11.0  
8     -11.0    -12.0  
9      -8.0     -9.0     
10     -8.0     -6.0   
11     -8.0     -5.0    
12     -8.0     -4.0   
13    -10.0      1.0    
14    -10.0      3.0   
15     -9.0     -9.0    
16     -6.0     -6.0   
17     -6.0     -6.0   
18     -4.0     -4.0  
19     -8.0      2.0    
20     -9.0      3.0      
21    -14.0      1.0 
22    -15.0     -3.0  
23    -17.0     -4.0   
24    -19.0     -6.0     
25    -60.0     -8.0   
26     -8.0     -8.0   
27     -9.0    -11.0    
28     -5.0      NaN    
29     -6.0      NaN    
30     -7.0      NaN
```

I would like to replace the -60 which is an outlier with the median using :

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - x.mean()) / x.std() < 4).all(axis=1)]
```

It works fine but it also delete all rows containing a NaN how can I avoid that ?

Output :

```
  January  February 
0      -5.0     -7.0 
1      -6.0     -6.0 
2      -5.0     -5.0  
3      -3.0     -6.0 
4      -6.0     -8.0   
5     -11.0     -9.0    
6      -6.0      5.0    
7      -8.0    -11.0  
8     -11.0    -12.0  
9      -8.0     -9.0     
10     -8.0     -6.0   
11     -8.0     -5.0    
12     -8.0     -4.0   
13    -10.0      1.0    
14    -10.0      3.0   
15     -9.0     -9.0    
16     -6.0     -6.0   
17     -6.0     -6.0   
18     -4.0     -4.0  
19     -8.0      2.0    
20     -9.0      3.0      
21    -14.0      1.0 
22    -15.0     -3.0  
23    -17.0     -4.0   
24    -19.0     -6.0     
25    -10.0     -8.0   
26     -8.0     -8.0   
27     -9.0    -11.0
```

As you can see, 3 rows have been deleted which is not very convenient. Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.isna()` in your logic:

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: (np.abs(x - x.mean()) / x.std() < 4) | x.isna()).all(axis=1)]
print(df)
```

Prints (notice index 25 (`-60.0`) is missing:

```
      January  February
0        -5.0      -7.0
1        -6.0      -6.0
2        -5.0      -5.0
3        -3.0      -6.0
4        -6.0      -8.0
5       -11.0      -9.0
6        -6.0       5.0
7        -8.0     -11.0
8       -11.0     -12.0
9        -8.0      -9.0
10       -8.0      -6.0
11       -8.0      -5.0
12       -8.0      -4.0
13      -10.0       1.0
14      -10.0       3.0
15       -9.0      -9.0
16       -6.0      -6.0
17       -6.0      -6.0
18       -4.0      -4.0
19       -8.0       2.0
20       -9.0       3.0
21      -14.0       1.0
22      -15.0      -3.0
23      -17.0      -4.0
24      -19.0      -6.0
26       -8.0      -8.0
27       -9.0     -11.0
28       -5.0       NaN
29       -6.0       NaN
30       -7.0       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy.where(...)`:

```py
df[["January", "February"]]=\
    np.where(
        df.sub(df.mean(axis=0)).abs()\
        .div(df.std(axis=0))>=4, 
        df.median(axis=0), df
    )
```

Output:

```py
    January  February
0      -5.0      -7.0
1      -6.0      -6.0
2      -5.0      -5.0
3      -3.0      -6.0
4      -6.0      -8.0
5     -11.0      -9.0
6      -6.0       5.0
7      -8.0     -11.0
8     -11.0     -12.0
9      -8.0      -9.0
10     -8.0      -6.0
11     -8.0      -5.0
12     -8.0      -4.0
13    -10.0       1.0
14    -10.0       3.0
15     -9.0      -9.0
16     -6.0      -6.0
17     -6.0      -6.0
18     -4.0      -4.0
19     -8.0       2.0
20     -9.0       3.0
21    -14.0       1.0
22    -15.0      -3.0
23    -17.0      -4.0
24    -19.0      -6.0
25     -8.0      -8.0
26     -8.0      -8.0
27     -9.0     -11.0
28     -5.0       NaN
29     -6.0       NaN
30     -7.0       NaN
```